# RESTful API - Getting HTTP 500 error all the time

Tags: java, rest, api, jersey, http-status-code-500

I am making a simple RESTful API to my application. I've made another package in my project (other from one where is my main java class, servlet, and model). And then I've made my resource file, very simple which looks like this:

```
package com.java.api;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("webservice")
public class ZipcodeService {

    @GET
    @Path("/lookup")
    public Response lookup() {
        return Response.ok().entity("Los Angeles").build();
    }
}
```

and this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" id="WebApp_ID"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <display-name>parking-space-booking-system</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.java.api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webservice/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am not using Maven. I am using Netbeans IDE and Tomcat server. I uploaded Jersey 2.25 all jar files to WEB-INF/lib folder. I am experimenting with web.xml to fix it but I have no more ideas. Here is the structure of my project:

[image]

Here is also my error message I got:

**HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception**

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.CommonProperties.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature.configure(JacksonFeature.java:69)
    org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:674)
    org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:610)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:800)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:367)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:162)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:304)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:301)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:311)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:169)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:359)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.27 logs.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.27

Comment: Learn to use Maven. It will not take long to learn the basics and it will make your life a lot easier,

Comment: I did learn Maven and change my project to maven. It is indeed a lot easier :) and there is no more this error of course.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look in (and post) your Tomcat logs. Look at `catalina.out`. It looks to me like your web.xml doesn't have a closing web-app tag, but that might just be because you didn't post the full web.xml.

Also, you need to package your application as a WAR file. Tomcat expects your web application WAR file to be located under the `webapps` directory.

edit:

the method wasn't found, therefore the appropriate JAR isn't actually on the classpath (lib folder).

```
org.glassfish.jersey.CommonProperties.getValue
```

Comment: I added error message. I'm searching for Catalina logs but I'm not able to find. Only logs I have in the Tomcat folder are older :( I'll search further if I found anything ill post it here.

Comment: I'm following instructions from 500 error: The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.27 logs. Apache Tomcat/8.0.27 but the folder is empty ;(

Comment: @Luke_Nuke see edit. you're missing a JAR for Jersey.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have problems with your libraries.

```
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.CommonProperties.getValue(..
```

by the server initialisation shows that you forgot to add some library (perhaps it's not in your Jersey 2.25, check for it). Your can also try to use another version of Jersey.